# How to represent a dataset in a network?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

Let's say I have data on users' profile information on a social network. So I have maybe this csv file for each user and their own attributes. Now I want to represent this social network so that I can do some network analysis or some classification task using collective classification. In general what is the best practice for storing these relationships so that I can import them later on or perhaps making the dataset available? I guess I have 3 main questions that stem from this general question:

What is the best practice in representing the undirected edges in the network?

What about directed edge?

What about edges with edge weights?

One example I can think of would be just have some adjacency matrix where we have 0 or no edge and 1 for edge (or the value of the edge weight if there is one), but this would blow up very fast with large amounts of data with sparse edges.

Answer (score 1):

Adjacency matrices are a good way to represent graphs: $A_{ij}=1$ if node $i$ connects to node $j$, otherwise zero. For undirected graphs, only the upper or lower triangle needs to be stored, as connections are symmetric. To prevent storage requirements from blowing up, use a sparse matrix datatype, which only needs to store the locations and values of the nonzero elements (in the case of a dense graph, there's simply no way around the issue). You can save additional space by using a sparse boolean matrix, as only 0/1 values need to be represented.

For weighted graphs, you can use a weight matrix where $W_{ij}$ contains the weight of the edge from node $i$ to node $j$, or zero if they're unconnected. As above, use a sparse matrix, and store only the upper/lower triangle for undirected graphs.